# Unable to download pdf in react application on host

Tags: html, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Download PDF-File won't work on AWS-Host.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import aa from "../media/AA.pdf";

export default class FileDownloader extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pdf">
                <a href={aa} download="aa.pdf">Download</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I tried with different method `<a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/media/AA.pdf"} download="AA.pdf">Download</a>` but same error

The media Folder is into `app/src/media/aa.pdf`

local it works fine by on the AWS host i can't download the file. The Browser tries to download but doesn't save. I use `AWS Amplify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Rewrites and redirects in AWS.

Add in a new rule or change existing rule `|pdf|`

- Source should be
  `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|pdf|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`
- Target address index.html
- Type 200 (Rewrite)